# display table css issue iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

Good day, Im creating a webpage with two(2) columns. The column 1 contain a PDF, I just emded it using `<iframe>`, then the column 2 is just like a comment sections. I don’t know if my decision is right, but I use `<div>` to make it like, a table with two columns.

**Here is the html code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='skin/css/user.css'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='cont'>
            <div class='wrap'>
                <div>
                    <iframe src='upload/1.pdf'></iframe>
                </div>  
                <div>
                    THIS IS THE SECOND COLUMN
                </div>                  
            </div>          
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Here is the css**

```
body,html{
    margin:0;
    height: 100%;
}
#cont{
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;   
}
#cont .wrap{
    display:table-row;
}
#cont .wrap div{
    display:table-cell;
}
#cont .wrap div:first-child{
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;   
}
iframe{
    width:100%;
    height: 70%;
}
#cont .wrap div:last-child{
    background-image:url('../img/user-comment-back.jpg');
    color: white;
    width:30%;

}
```

There is no problem in layout it suite what I what, but the problem is the column 2 content is align to the bottom of column 1 content. Here is the screen shot,
[image]

Can someone explained me why it acts like that, and what should be the solution? Thank you

Comment: Do u have live page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add `vertical-align:top;` in the div. when you use `table` CSS property to align 2 div horizontally, then its behave like table and text start from bottom.

you just need to add this line;

```
#cont .wrap div{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:top; /*Added line*/
}
```

Here is a Demo link. http://jsbin.com/relutute/1/

Comment: so its a natural thing? and must remember that when creating a table using div always declare its vertical alignment.

Comment: yes those property make table structure also have a same  table properties. when the height is increase the text by default stay at bottom and then we've to define `vertical:top` if we want to move at `top` or `middle`.

Comment: Happier with the answer?